# show AB has n real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a postive integer. Assume that $A,B\in{\mathcal{R}^{n\times n}}$ are two symmetric real matrices, and one of them is symmetric postive definite. Show that the matrix AB has $n$ real eigenvalues.
This is a problem from qualified exam.